# Why does creating this View cause Error 1350 when the SQL runs properly in an SQL tab?

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-workbench

Using MySQLWorkbench, when I try to create this view:

SELECT myAttribute01, myAttribute02, myAttribute03
INTO @myVar01 , @myVar02, @myVar03
FROM mytable01 
WHERE myAttribute01 = 1;

I get a 1350 error. However, I ***can*** execute the above SQL from an SQL tab with no problems. I only get the error when I try to make it into a view.   See attached screen snip.
[image: Error 1350]

Answer (score 2):

As written in the error, you can't use a "SELECT ... INTO" statement to create a view.

[Futhermore as written in the guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)

> A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> The SELECT statement cannot refer to system variables or **user-defined variable**s.

Comment: I guess I deserved that. :)

Comment: In fact I didn't remembered that, i have written a query to avoid the "INTO" then when I test id I got error 1351 :D

Comment: error 1351 view's select contains a variable or parameter ;)